# Не получается установить debian на MacBook не работает rEFInd

Tags: debian, macos, mac, boot, macbook

Записал образ debian на флешку. Выбрал тот, что  debian-mac-8.6.0-amd64-netinst.iso. Проверил на компьютере, установщик загружается нормально, но загрузиться с флешки на маке не получается. Включаю ноутбук, зажимаю alt, но в меню загрузки только диск с мак осью, флешки нет, сколько я не ждал ее появления. После нескольких перезгагрузок установил rEFInd. Правда, я сначала ступил, перепутал rEFInd с rEFIt и поставил его. Он не заработал вообще: грузился стандартный маковски загрузчик. Потом поставил rEFInd. Запустил стандартный установочный скрипт. Он сообщил, что обнаружена установленая версия загрузчика и порекомендовал запустить установщик из режима востановления. Я загрузился в режим востановления, запустил установщик. Он все установил, написал, что проблем нет. После перезагрузки я увидел rEFInd и варианты загрузиться с жесткого диска с MacOs или с флешки с линуксом. Я выбрал флешку, но загрузка не началась. Индикатор на флешке погас, на экране появилась надпись

> No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key

после чего на флешке зажегся индикатор. Нажатие на разные клавиши не вызвало никакаой реакции. Пришлось вырубить компьютер пинудительно через кнопку выключения. Загрузка в Mac Os проходила нормально. После этого я зашел в режим востановления и в терминале выполнил

> csrutil disable

Чтобы вырубить System Integrity Projection. Потом снова запустил скрипт установки rEFInd но ничего не изменилось. Так каже мне установить debian на MacBook? Модель A1278(MacBook Pro 13, кажется 2011 года)

Comment: Я конечно не все понимаю, но зачем тратись много*k денег на мак, и ставить на него линукс)

Comment: @CodeStealer Ну, во первых, я же не сношу мак ось, ставлю дуал бут. Во вторых, хорошее железо - это хорошо, но хорошее железо плюс нормальная ось - гораздо лучше))) (не в обиду яблочникам - это только мое мнение). В любом случае мак не покупался для линуха. Просто так получилось, что мне понадобился ноут и одновременно появился никому не нужный, старый мак.

Comment: ну тогда понятно. Я в делах с ОСями предпочитаю простоту, понятность, комформ и красивый интерфейс) По-этому, мне, как обычному пользователю Окошек не нравится ни макОсь ни линукс) Слишком уж много надо разбираться в этих делах. Но спасибо за ответ.